# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Cкажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли ставить запятую перед словом Сторона? "В случае наступления форс-мажорных обстоятельств, Сторона, для которой надлежащее исполнение обязательств оказалось невозможным, должна в ...

Answer (score 3):

Обособление обстоятельственного оборота с производным предлогом (в случае) не обязательно. Чаще всего происходит обособление, если оборот стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым. В Вашем случае постановка запятой остается на Ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно согласен с мнением Ларf относительно того, что знаки препинания в данном случае можно оставить на усмотрение автора. Главным судьёй в данном случае  в пользу того или иного пунктуационного решения может быть Ваша интонация при произношении сего предложения.

Comment: @alexander, убирайте пожалуйста лишние пробелы в начале сообщения.
Если, конечно, хотиите, чтобы его прочитали все.

Comment: Спасибо, учту.

Comment: а интонация зависит от вкладываемого смысла. В чем разница смыслов при   наличии и отсутствии запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая опциональна, но лучше поставить.
Фраза очень распространённая, без обособления оборот плохо воспринимается даже зрительно.
Ну и потом есть традиция...

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не ставить, поскольку обстоятельство стоит в начале предложения.Знак факультативный.

Comment: факультативность - можем ставить запятую или нет в зависимости от того, что хотим сказать. 

В случае наступления форс-мажорных обстоятельств Сторона должна в ...

В случае наступления форс-мажорных обстоятельств, Сторона должна в .

В чем разница между этими предложениями по смыслу?